# How can you set an OnChangeListener to a radio_group in android with ActivityMainBinding?

Tags: android-studio

I'm a beginner doing [Android Kotlin training](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-polished-user-experience?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-2-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-polished-user-experience#6).

I want to make the button redundant by adding listeners to all the inputs.  The [solution MainActivity.kt](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-tip-calculator-app-solution/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/tiptime/MainActivity.kt) already has a listener for the text input "cost_of_service_edit_text":
`binding.costOfServiceEditText.setOnKeyListener`.

**How do you add a radio group listener with `ActivityMainBinding`?**

The solution [layout](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-basics-kotlin-tip-calculator-app-solution/blob/main/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) names the radio group "tip_options".

I tried adding
`binding.tipOptions.setOnClickListener{ _ ->  handleEvent() }`

which didn't crash but also didn't run the `handleEvent()` function, when I changed the selection in the radio group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to capture each `RadioButton` action event in the RadioGroup. In the sample app, they are capturing the event on `CalculateButton` first. Then in the `CaptureButton` handler method, they are checking which `RadioButton` was clicked here:

```
when (binding.tipOptions.checkedRadioButtonId) {
            R.id.option_twenty_percent -> 0.20
            R.id.option_eighteen_percent -> 0.18
            else -> 0.15
        }
```

If you want to know further, check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton)

Comment: Thank you.  I added    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" to each Radio Button and added    fun onRadioButtonClicked(view: View)  to the MainActivity class